# How to increase the power of mantra?

Tags: mantras

How to increase the power of mantra, if we stopped believing the mantra by mistake?

Is there a conductor to increase the power of mantra?

Comment: If you have stopped believing in the mantra its power will not decrease because of that. You can again start chanting it with faith.

Comment: The power of mantra will remain as it whether you recite it or not but for you individually it will be beneficial only if you chant it persistently with full faith .... so bottom line is persistence in doing something despite difficulty or delay in achieving success.

Comment: What use is of mantra if it's all a matter a faith?

Comment: are you asking for daily practice or as a seeker?

Comment: @Lokesh a person under devotional influence can be very powerful.

Comment: @KauvaAatma I am not arguing that. I am asking what's the need of reciting a complicated mantra if all that matters is the person believing it works.

Comment: @Lokesh it's a psychological thing about rewards. a complex answer reinforces confidence in the process used to achieve it. I agree that Japa would be just as effective, but it would not reinforce confidence in the methodology.

Answer (score 1):

Human beings are susceptible to dejection or frustration while doing austerities in SPIRITUAL path.  Saints advise to keep on trying until perfection has been achieved, forgetting about downfalls.

The following are  excerpts from the teachings of Sri Ramana Maharshi.

1.

> D.: When an endeavour is made to lead the right life and to
>   concentrate thought on the Self, ***there is often a downfall and
>   break. What is to be done?***
>
> M.: It will come all right in the end. **There is the steady impulse
>   of your determination that sets you on your feet again after every
>   downfall and breakdown.** Gradually the obstacles are all overcome and
>   your current becomes stronger. ***Everything comes right in the
>   end.*** Steady determination is what is required.

---

2.

> D.: What is dhyana?
>
> M.: Dhyana is holding on to a single thought and putting off all other
>   thoughts.
>
> D.: What is to be meditated upon?
>
> M.: Anything that you prefer.
>
> D.: Siva, Vishnu, and Gayatri are said to be equally efficacious.
>   Which  should I meditate upon?
>
> M.: Any one you like best. They are all equal in their effect. But you
>   should stick to one.
>
> D.: How to meditate?
>
> M.: Concentrate on that one whom you like best. If a single thought 
>   prevails, all other thoughts are put off and finally eradicated. So 
>   long as diversity prevails there are bad thoughts. When the object  of
>   love prevails only good thoughts hold the field. Therefore hold  on to
>   one thought only. Dhyana is the chief practice.

A little later Sri Bhagavan continued:

> Dhyana means fight. As soon as you begin meditation other  thoughts
>   will crowd together, gather force and try to sink the single thought
>   to which you try to hold. The good thought must gradually gain
>   strength by repeated practice. After it has grown strong the other
>   thoughts will be put to flight.  This is the battle royal always
>   taking place in meditation.